# module javafx.base cannot access class application.customer (in module FCR) because module FCR does not open application to javafx.base

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am trying to display data in tableView in javafx.

Even though I have used SimpleStringProperty and SimpleIntegerProperty, every time I click "Check Customers" button, I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module javafx.base cannot access class application.customer (in module FCR) because module FCR does not open application to javafx.base
>
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:69)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.PropertyReference.getProperty(PropertyReference.java:197)
> ... 98 more

This is the code of customer:

```
public class customer {

private final IntegerProperty ID;
private final StringProperty  firstName;
private final StringProperty  lastName;
private final StringProperty  carPlate;
private final IntegerProperty telephoneNum;

public customer(int ID,String firstName, String lastName, String carPlate, int telephoneNum) {
    this.ID = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.carPlate = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.telephoneNum = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    setID(ID);
    setfirstName(firstName);
    setlastName(lastName);
    setcarPlate(carPlate);
    settelephoneNum(telephoneNum);
}

public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
    return firstName;
}

public final String getfirstName() {
    return firstName.get();
}

public final void setfirstName(String fname) {
    firstName.set(fname);
}

public final IntegerProperty IDProperty() {
    return ID;
}

public final int getID() {
    return ID.get();
}

public final void setID(int iD) {
    ID.set(iD);
}

public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
    return lastName;
}

public final String getlastName() {
    return lastName.get();
}

public final void setlastName(String lname) {
    lastName.set(getfirstName());;
}

public final IntegerProperty telephoneNumProperty() {
    return telephoneNum;
}

public final int gettelephoneNum() {
    return telephoneNum.get();
}

public final void settelephoneNum(int tnum) {
    telephoneNum.set(tnum);;
}

public final StringProperty carPlateProperty() {
    return carPlate;
}

public final String getcarPlate() {
    return carPlate.get();
}

public final void setcarPlate(String platenum) {
    carPlate.set(platenum);
}
```

And here is the controller:

```
public class checkCustomers {

private customersData q = Main.q;

@FXML
private TableView table;


@FXML
private TableColumn firstName;
@FXML
private TableColumn lastName;
@FXML
private TableColumn carPlate;
@FXML
private TableColumn telephoneNumber;


@FXML
public void initialize() {
    
System.out.println(1);

firstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<customer, String>("firstName"));
lastName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<customer, String>("lastName"));
carPlate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<customer, String>("carPlate"));
telephoneNumber.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<customer, Integer>("telephoneNumber"));
table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(q.getAllCustomers()));
}
```

The module-info.java code is:

```
module FCR {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.sql;
    requires javafx.base;

    opens application to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
}
```

I think I should add something in the module-info can anyone please help?

Comment: Why not include `opens application to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml, javafx.base;` ? Or maybe `export application` though it isn't clear what application is.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Open Your Package to `javafx.base`

The `PropertyValueFactory` class uses reflection to get the named property. You have to grant that class's module (`javafx.base`) the necessary access to your code in order for this reflection to work.

Change:

```java
opens application to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
```

To:

```java
opens application to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml, javafx.base;
```

---

### Use a Lambda Expression

The other option is to not use `PropertyValueFactory`. That class was most likely created because JavaFX was released before lambda expressions were added in Java 8. It made declaring value factories less verbose, but it has two problems:

1. It uses reflection.

   - Not necessarily bad, but reflection should be avoided if possible.
2. There's no compile-time safety.

   - If the needed methods don't exist in the model class, or if the methods return the wrong type, then you'll only find out about it at run-time.

Using a lambda expression avoids both those problems. For example:

```java
lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().lastNameProperty());
```

---

### Don't Use Raw Types

Check out the [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) Q&A. You're using the raw type of `TableView` and `TableColumn`. Don't do that; declare the type arguments.